# Perl Text Parsing - fixed delimeted structure is changing

Tags: perl

Perl Experts - My attempt to solve my problem is turning into a lot of code, which in PERL seems like I'm approaching this in-correctly. Here is my problem:

I have a block of text (example below) which can have variable amount of whitespace between the column data. I was using a simple split, but the problem now is that the column "code" now contains spaces in the data (I only accounted for that in the last column). What seems to be constant (although I don't have access to, or control of the source structure) is that there is a minimum of 3 spaces between columns (maybe more, but never less).

So, I'd like to say my column delimiter token is "3 spaces" and then trim the data within each to have my actual columnar data.

```
COL0   COL1   COL2   COL3         COL4   COL5
   -      4    0.2      1       416489   463455 554
          1    0.9      1           E1   
   0      3    1.4     14   E97-TEST 1   
   -      1   97.5    396         PASS   Good
```

I'm just trying to get the values into 6 variables.

NOTE: COL0 may not have a value. COL4 may contain space in data. COL5 may contain no value, or data with space. All fixed formatting is done with spaces (no tabs or other special characters). To clarify -- the columns are NOT consistently sized. One file might have COL4 as 13 characters, another have COL4 with 21 characters wide. Or not strict as another SO member stated.

Comment: Can a column start from a different offset between each row? E..g. row1 is `|   1   2   3|` (3 spaces) and row2 is `|   11111   2   3|` (also 3 spaces, but second column now starts with offset 4 bigger than in the first row due to the fact that first value in row2 is so wide)

Comment: No, the column sizing is consistent for all data rows per file. Can differentiate between files, but consistent within the file.

Comment: Are the column headings really present?

Comment: Are column headers (ie COL0 COL1 COL2 ..) always present? You could potentially figure out the offset and length of each column from the first line and then use that to parse the rest of the file

Comment: I think Svante and vmpstr are onto something... I noticed that COL0 through COL4 have RIGHT aligned data, COL5 is LEFT. The column titles are constant values (known) so I should be able to use that location and work backwards until I hit the next column offset.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to figure out where the columns are. As a really quite disgusting hack, you can read the whole file in and then string-or the lines together:

```
my @file = <file>;
chomp @file;

my $t = "";
$t |= $_ foreach(@file);
```

$t will then contain space characters in columns only where there were always space characters in that column; other columns will contain binary junk. Now split it with a zero-width match that matches the non-space:

```
my @cols = split /(?=[^ ]+)/, $t;
```

We actually want the *widths* of the columns to generate an unpack() format:

```
@cols = map length, @cols;
my $format = join '', map "A$_", @cols;
```

Now process the file! :

```
foreach my $line (@file) {
  my($field, $field2, ...) = unpack $format, $line;
  your code here...
}
```

(This code has only been lightly tested.)

Comment: My text block is actually just a subset of a larger file that has many such blocks (all with different columns structures). I do know the start and end of my block, not sure how to get into single line... guess I can concatenate the lines?

Comment: I was unable to get this to work for me. With my limited knowledge of PERL I could not figure out where I was in trouble. I ended up using simple substr since with Svante and vmpstr's help I realized that the header titles are known constants. Using that I was able to find the right edge of all the columns, then substr the space in-between. With some trim I was able to get what I want with dynamic column widths. I'm sure this type of solution is better, but as it is with PERL, it stumped me in my short time I could allocate to solving this problem. Thanks All!

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with strict columnar data like this, [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) is probably what you want:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = <<EOD;
COL0   COL1   COL2   COL3         COL4   COL5
   -      4    0.2      1       416489   463455 554
          1    0.9      1           E1   
   0      3    1.4     14   E97-TEST 1   
   -      1   97.5    396         PASS   Good
EOD

my @lines = split '\n', $data;
for my $line ( @lines ) {
    my @values = unpack("a5 A7 A7 A7 A13 A*", $line);
    print Dumper \@values;
}
```

This appears to dump out your values into the `@values` array as you wish, but they'll have leading spaces that you'll have to trim off.

Comment: It sounds like it might not be **strict** columnar data, but a bit uncler

Comment: Thank you for this method, didn't know about it. However, another part of my challenge is the column sizes can vary. That is why I was thinking of focusing on the 3 character token, as COL4 may not always be 13 characters wide (have data files with COL4 being 13 to 21 characters wide).

Answer (score 1):

I would use two passes: in the first, find those character columns that have a space in each line; then, split or unpack with those indices.  Whitespace trimming is done afterwards.

Your example:

```
COL0   COL1   COL2   COL3         COL4   COL5
   -      4    0.2      1       416489   463455 554
          1    0.9      1           E1   
   0      3    1.4     14   E97-TEST 1   
   -      1   97.5    396         PASS   Good

000011100001110000111000011100000000001110000000000
```

The `1`s in the last line show which columns are all spaces.

Comment: So, use the column titles to define the TEMPLATE then pass those values to UNPACK? I'm going to try that now.

Comment: @Walinmichi:  no, use _all_ lines to define the template.

Comment: I do not understand. The entire file contains many more of these types of blocks, all of different structures. I have code that gets me to the right block. I even know the end of the block, because there is an "*****END*******" constant below each block.

Answer (score 0):

I know CanSpice already answered (possibly a much better solution), but you can set the input delimiter using "$/".  This must be done in a local scope (probably a sub) as it is a global variable, or you may see side effects. Ex:

```
local $/ = "   ";
$input = <DATAIN>; # assuming DATAIN is the file-handler
```

You can trim whitespace using a nice little regex.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_%28programming%29#Perl) for an example.